# C++ EOF on cout<<char(int) casting

Tags: c++, char, eof

Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int duze[26];
    int male[26];
    int n;
    //cout<<int('a')<<endl<<int('A');
    cin>>n;

    char temp;
    for (int i=0; i<27; i++)
        male[i]=0;
    for (int i=0; i<27; i++)
        duze[i]=0;

    while (n>=0)
    {
        cin.get(temp);
        if (temp=='\n') { n--; continue;}
        if (temp==' ') continue;
        if (temp>='a' && temp<='z')
            male[temp-'a']++;
        else if (temp>='A' && temp<='Z')
            duze[temp-'A']++;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<27; i++)
        if (male[i]>0) cout<<char(i+'a')<<" "<<male[i]<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<27; i++)
        if (duze[i]>0) cout<<char(i+'A')<<" "<<duze[i]<<endl;
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The program counts letters in given n lines of text. The letters that dont exist are skipped.
When I run it in console it looks ok, but I know that there are EOF characters before characters...
How can I avoid it?

Comment: Note array indexes run from `0` to `N-1`, where `N` is the number of elements: all of the `for` loops access 1 too many.

Comment: "I know that there are EOF characters before characters". And how do you know that?

Comment: oh, didnt see that ;) thanx. Add reply so I can mark it as correct. :D

Comment: @Rob well, trust me I know it, Im 100% sure :P

Comment: What do you mean by EOF characters? EOF isn't a character.

Comment: @kittyPL - Let me rephrase. What do you observe? Since there is no such thing in the world as an "EOF character", I'm very curious to know what you are actually seeing.

Comment: @Rob the programs output is checked character by character by another program that compares it to the correct output, It says that there should be 'a' and there was EOF.

Comment: That means that your output stops before it should have. I suspect that your buffer overflow is corrupting the `n` variable. Fix the bugs identified below and see if it gets better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array indexes run from `0` to `N-1`, where `N` is the number of elements: all of the `for` loops access 1 too many resulting in undefined behaviour. Change terminating conditions on `for` loops to `i < 26`.

Another minor note, to simplify the initialization of `duze` and `male` you declare them as:

```
int duze[26] = { 0 };
int male[26] = { 0 };
```

This set all elements to `0`, meaning you can remove the two `for` loops that currently do this.

Comment: 8 mins due to site limits, and checked. You were first :D

Answer (score 3):

You have a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) (several of them, actually).  You declare two arrays of size 26 (`duze` and `male`), but then you proceed to write data into 27 indices (0 through 26).

Since this is outside the bounds of the buffer, you're stomping on other memory, which causes erratic, unpredictable behavior.  The C++ standard calls this **undefined behavior**: once you do this, absolutely anything could happen: your program could crash, it could have subtle errors like this, it could appear to work correctly, or it could even erase your hard drive (though that's rather unlikely).

To fix this, change all of your 27's into 26's; you could also increase the array size to 27, but then printing out `char(26+'a')` would give you `{`, which is probably not your intent.

Comment: Or make the loops stop at 25 instead of 26

Answer (score 2):

You should check the following:

```
if ( cin.get(temp) )
{
  // read was ok
}
else
{
  // eof or other issue on read
}
```